# Setting up a master DNS server, using goDaddy as slave

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, godaddy

I have a server hosting several domains and a DNS premium account at GoDaddy. I would like one of the domains I own, xxx.co, to become the master nameserver for all the other domains, and to use GoDaddy's as my secondary/slave.

I'm an ignorant on DNS so please forgive my misknowledge.

First I may mention the goal of this operation: I use Virtualmin on my server, and its API which, when adding a domain, creates all the DNS records (in BIND 9.7) according to templates I configured.This includes SPF, and as I have spam problems, my server being often registered as spammer, I think it might contribute to solve the problem, and also avoid any manual work in GoDaddy's interface when taking care of a new domain.

In GoDaddy interface, which manages this domain, I add two hosts called ns1.xxx.co and ns2.xxx.co pointing to my server's IP as described [here](http://community.godaddy.com/help/article/668?locale=en). Then I configure the zone on my server:

```
    $ttl 3600s
    @   IN  SOA wpcxxxx.amenworld.com. root.wpcxxxx.amenworld.com. (
                1302825306
                10800
                3600
                604800
                38400 )
    @   IN  NS  wpcxxxx.amenworld.com.
    xxx.co. IN  A   62.193.xxx.xxx
    www.xxx.co. IN  A   62.193.xxx.xxx
    ftp.xxx.co. IN  A   62.193.xxx.xxx
    m.xxx.co.   IN  A   62.193.xxx.xxx
    localhost.xxx.co.   IN  A   127.0.0.1
    xxx.co. IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx a:xxx.co ip4:62.193.xxx.xxx?all"
    ns1.xxx.co. IN  NS  wpcxxxx.amenworld.com.
    ns2.xxx.co. IN  NS  wpcxxxx.amenworld.com.
    ns1.xxx.co. IN  A   62.193.xxx.xxx
    ns2.xxx.co. IN  A   62.193.xxx.xxx
```

At this point, I wonder if this domain xxx.co can use its own domain-based nameservers or if it has to stick with the ones from GoDaddy. I tried both.
So I use a second domain example.com, add it on my server through Virtualmin, and I set GoDaddy's as secondary/slave for example.com. Then I want to set ns1.xxx.co and ns2.xxx.co as example's nameservers but instead get this error:

```
The modifications you requested for the domain XXX.CO have FAILED.
Error: Name server pending addition is not registered: NS1.XXX.CO
```

Am I right in the first place to wish to achieve this? Will it be usefull for my spam problem? Is there any downside I don't see?

What's happening with this error message? How can I achieve this?
I've followed the steps from [here](http://community.godaddy.com/help/article/797?locale=en#slave), I have opened my port 953 - was it usefull btw?
Do I have to add ns1.xxx.co and ns2.xxx.co in the hosts file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, first things first: Go to you local book store (or library if it's got a decent selection of technical books) and pick up a copy of [DNS & BIND](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596100575) - any edition will be sufficient, though if you're buying one buy the latest.  Then read this book cover to cover, or at least read through chapters 1, 2, 3, 5 and 6.

I am absolutely serious about this - If you try to set up DNS without a solid understanding of what's going on you are in for a wold of pain, suffering and mysterious breakage.  Spending a day with a good book on DNS will pay for itself the first time you have a problem.

---

**Now to actually answer your questions :-)**

Re: the issue of being flagged as spam: Hosting your own DNS may or may not solve the problem of your system being flagged as a spam source -- The question you haven't asked/answered is **WHY** you are being flagged as a spam source (Is it your IP, the lack of SPF records, a bad reverse-DNS entry, or is your server perhaps misconfigured and really being used to send spam?).
You need to answer that question first, then pursue solutions based on what you discover.

*If after investigating the incident problem you still want to host your own DNS (either as part of a solution to the incident problem, or just for the experience) . . .*

I'm pretty sure the error you're getting from GoDaddy is their way of saying you're missing glue records -- In plain English "You want us to use `ns1.xxx.com` as a nameserver for `xxx.com`, but we have no way of finding that server".

Prior to using a host within in your own zone as an NS you need to create glue records for it.  You can do this in GoDaddy's domain manager's "Host" box -- Add a domain host for each NS you want to use, and the system should then let you specify those hosts as the domain's nameservers.

---

> **BIG IMPORTANT WARNING**
>   Before you flip the switch check, *double-check* and **triple-check** that the servers you're about to set as the authoritative NS are working properly (they resolve all the names they're supposed to resolve, you can query them from a machine off your network, etc.).
>
> Many admins (probably every one who has ever set up DNS) probably has a horror story about screwing up and knocking their domain off the internet for a while -- Don't be a statistic like the rest of us :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I went to check the reasons of my spam (yeah, I could have done that before spending 3 days on this), and the problem seems to reside in "misdirected bounces or misdirected autoresponders", and had nothing to do with DNS. I corrected the problem straight away as it was 2 very old and unused addresses flowed with spam and with autoanswer on. I'll try to replicate the SPF records generated by Virtualmin in my Premium DNS templates, and I think I'll abandon my idea of rolling my own DNS server before I know the stuff in-depth. I'll get this book you recommend. Cheers!